# If someone is electrocuted, do they have to die or can they just be injured?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

Is it correct to say I electrocuted my friend if he was only injured by electricity?

Comment: Actually, the only part of that phrase I'd have a problem with is "friend"... <g>

Comment: http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/electrocute.html  and  http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Electric_shock

Comment: @MT_Head What does "<g>" mean?

Comment: @JoeZeng - I believe it's short for "grin"; in any case it's an emoticon to indicate that what I've just typed is a joke.

Comment: Well, I learned something new.

Comment: Huh, and here I thought this word could apply to someone licking a 9 volt battery.

Answer (score 41):

The term *electrocute* was originally coined in 1889[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=electrocute) by splicing the prefix *electro-* into the word *execute*. It originally meant *execute (by electric shock)*. However, its meaning has evolved over time: first to also include *accidental* death by electric shock and later to include electrical *injury*,[²](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/electrocute) generally serious in nature. So your use of the word does not fit the original nineteenth century meaning, but is perfectly in line with the broader meaning of the word as it is understood today.

Comment: [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/electrocute) and nearly all of the [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/electrocute) entries, do not agree that this word has "evolved" (nor Wiki, outside of British English).

Comment: Actually, the first few attempted electrocutions (ie, executions via electric shock) failed, though prior to that a number of people (probably hundreds) were killed by what we would now call "accidental electrocution".

Comment: @Mazura Oxford is a reputable source. [It attests this meaning in American English also.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/electrocute) [So does the Macmillan, another reputable source.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/electrocute) I go to these frequently because of the quality of their research. The Free Dictionary has its uses, but despite its name it is not a dictionary. Rather it is a compilation from free sources, notably 19th century dictionaries. M-W is reliable if you go to the unabridged.

Comment: @HotLicks - "What about those bank robbers? The ones that made that suicide pact." - "Did they commit suicide?" - "Obviously not, Damon." - "Then they're unreliable." (The Running Man, 1987)

Comment: @MετάEd - I wouldn't use an American dictionary to *attest* to British English.

Comment: @Mazura, TFD compiles from *American Heritage* Fifth Ed. (2011), *Collins* 12th (2014), *Random House* (unspecified, possibly 2011), etc. In short, 21st century sources. If up-to-the-minute rumors (for example, misinformation based on the premise that words, rather than statements, make implications) are desired, *Wiktionary* or independent research is needed.

Comment: MW has "to kill or severely injure by electric shock" so I guess they've updated since Mazura's comment.

Answer (score 19):

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/electrocute) says:

> electrocute: *injure* or *kill* (someone) by electric shock.

So, yes, if someone is electrocuted, they can just be injured.

Comment: Is that like the People's Front of Judea?

Comment: People's Front of Judea? Splitters!

Comment: *Electrocution is death caused by electric shock... In* ***British English*** *the word also covers non-fatal injuries* -[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocution)

Answer (score 12):

My husband is an electrician. He reports that in the industry, *electrocute* is always used to mean death by electricity.  They say *electrified* or (colloquially) *lifted* to mean receiving an electric shock that is not fatal.

Answer (score 6):

You will sometimes see people use it incorrectly when they actually mean *shock* or, in other words, when someone or something receives an electrical current.

Electrocution actually derives from *electricity* + *execute*: “to put to death by means of electricity”. So the correct usage means that someone or something has been killed via powerful electrical current.

Also I may mention that an electrocution also implies the intent of death. So you may electrocute your friend if the intended outcome is their demise, though they may live through it.

Comment: The two dictionaries I consulted agree with you. From *American Heritage*, 4th ed.:"**electrocute** 1.To kill with electricity: *a worker who was electrocuted by a high-tension wire* 2. To execute (a condemned prisoner) by means of electricity." And from *Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary*, 30th ed.: **electrocution**: the taking of life by passage of electric current through the body"

Comment: @JLG: I think there might be differences in usage between AmE and BrE due to the fact that in US  death penalty is still frequently applied by electrocute. This method is completely unknown for Brits. However, even the NOAD has a 'special usage' in the sense you are recalled.

Comment: @Carlo_R, Interesting point, though it is NOT true that the death penalty "is still frequently applied" by electrocution in the U.S. Electrocution is no longer used in the U.S., except if an inmate in certain states chooses it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_chair

Comment: "*Electrocution actually derives from Electricity + Execute or, to put to death by means of electricity. So, the correct usage means that someone or something has been killed via powerful electrical current.*" The conclusion may be correct, but the argument is 100% bogus. The derivation of a word tells us *nothing whatsoever* about its correct usage. This is the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the degree of precision that’s appropriate for the register you are talking or speaking in.

In more formal use, *electrocute* would only refer to execution with electricity.

In less formal use, it could refer both to an accidental killing, and a mere injury.

This sense is later, came into the language by extension in colloquial use, and – pertinent to your question – is considered incorrect by some and is at odds with its etymology. It’s this last that makes it better avoided when a formal register or precise use is intended; in day-to-day use it won’t matter that some people might argue pedantically against it, but other times you want to be free from even the worse stickler’s arguments.

Comment: If we allow electrocution survivors, next stop is non-lethal executions, immobile automobiles, inaudible telephones and invisible televisions.  No sorry the slippery-pope fallacy doesn't apply..

Answer (score 2):

Unless the injury is life-threatening or at least very severe, I would recommend “I shocked him”, maybe adding “with electricity” if it’s not clear enough from the context.

Answer (score 2):

You could try saying, “I electrified my friend!”

Not precisely what you’re looking for, but at least we’ll know you made a big impression on your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with other words, drowning is necessarily a form of death but shooting is primarily a source of injury. How do we want to view electrocution? It’s all in the mind, I suppose.

Comment: The difference lies in the root of the word - 'cution' refers to a method of death.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, using "electrocute" to refer to serious, non-fatal injury is acceptable, but I would advise against it; people who know the correct formal definition may think someone died.

Answer (score 0):

Both fatally and injuriously:

> 2001   Times (Nexis) 28 July   *In Georgia I stood outside death row as the state electrocuted a man I thought was probably innocent.*

> 1988   Courier-Mail (Brisbane) (Nexis) 10 May   *I was electrocuted. I can still smell the flesh burning.*

Like much of English, a word is understood in context.